# Prev page URL when I am redirecting in getServerSideProps (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, redirect, next.js

I am still pretty new with Next.js and all this SSR stuff, so I need an advice.
Here is my situation:

I have a page behind auth and I am trying to do some pre-fetching:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<SomeProps> = async ({ req, res }) => {
  try {
    const data = await fetchOnServerSide<Data[]>(someAPI, req, {
      method: 'GET',
    });
    return {
      props: data, // will be passed to the page component as props
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // Oops, you aren't authed for doing it or your token expired -> go to the "login page"
    if (res) {
      res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/login' });
      res.end();
    }
    return { props: {} };
  }
};
```

And it works, but I want to redirect my fellow user back from login page after successful authentication.
How can I get prev page URL in that case?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your login page look like?

Comment: I've tried Router.back() but it works only with client-side redirects.
Now I just redirect user at main page with router.push('/');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the current page as a query param to the login page when redirecting. Then, in your login page, you could redirect back to it once login is successful.

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<SomeProps> = async ({ req }) => {
    try {
        const data = await fetchOnServerSide<Data[]>(someAPI, req, { method: 'GET' });
        return {
            props: data
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return { 
            redirect: {
                destination: '/login?from=current-page', // Replace `current-page` with the actual page
                statusCode: 302,
            } 
        };
    }
};
```

I'd recommend you return the `redirect` object from `getServerSideProps` rather than calling `res.writeHead` for a more idiomatic approach.